# error while running gem5 full system mode on arm

Tags: gem5

i installed gem5 simulator on ubuntu 14.04. then i used the youtube guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd_DtxQD5kc) to run gem5 in full system mode in ARM architecture. first i downloaded arm-system-2011-08.tar.bz2 as mentioned in the video then i run below command:

```
build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/morteza/full_system_images/disks/arm-ubuntu-natty-headless.img --kernel=/home/morteza/full_system_images/binaries/vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.2.6.38.8
```

but i encountered this output. can abybody please help me?

p.s: i added --kernel option and rename bootloader in /fulls_system_image/binaries from boot.arm to boot_emm.arm because of some errors about not finding bootloader and kernel. this is my final output which i brought hereunder. i' ll appreciate if anybody tell what is the problem.

OUTPUT:

```
gem5 Simulator System.  http://gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 compiled Jan  3 2020 05:49:20
gem5 started Jan  3 2020 17:16:17
gem5 executing on morteza-pc, pid 2499
command line: build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/morteza/full_system_images/disks/arm-ubuntu-natty-headless.img --kernel=/home/morteza/full_system_images/binaries/vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.2.6.38.8

warn: Can only correctly generate a dtb for VExpress_GEM5_V1 platforms, unless custom hardware models have been equipped with generation functionality.
Global frequency set at 1000000000000 ticks per second
warn: DRAM device capacity (8192 Mbytes) does not match the address range assigned (512 Mbytes)
info: kernel located at: /home/morteza/full_system_images/binaries/vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.2.6.38.8
warn: Bootloader entry point 0x80000000 overriding reset address 0
system.vncserver: Listening for connections on port 5900
system.terminal: Listening for connections on port 3456
0: system.remote_gdb: listening for remote gdb on port 7000
info: Using bootloader at address 0x80000000
info: Using kernel entry physical address at 0x80008000
warn: DTB file specified, but no device tree support in kernel
**** REAL SIMULATION ****
warn: Existing EnergyCtrl, but no enabled DVFSHandler found.
info: Entering event queue @ 0.  Starting simulation...
warn: Device system.membus.badaddr_responder accessed by read to address 0x10009018 size=4
gem5.opt: build/ARM/cpu/simple/atomic.cc:418: virtual Fault AtomicSimpleCPU::readMem(Addr, uint8_t*, unsigned int, Request::Flags, const std::vector<bool>&): Assertion `!pkt.isError()' failed.
Program aborted at tick 30500
--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_Z15print_backtracev+0x15)[0x1d505e5]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_Z12abortHandleri+0x36)[0x1d5a796]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10330)[0x7f41e3962330]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f41e1eacc37]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f41e1eb0028]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2fbf6)[0x7f41e1ea5bf6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2fca2)[0x7f41e1ea5ca2]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN15AtomicSimpleCPU7readMemEmPhj5FlagsImERKSt6vectorIbSaIbEE+0x538)[0x1e4eca8]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN17SimpleExecContext7readMemEmPhj5FlagsImERKSt6vectorIbSaIbEE+0x21)[0x1e5c5b1]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_Z13readMemAtomicI11ExecContextjESt10shared_ptrI9FaultBaseEPT_PN5Trace10InstRecordEmRT0_5FlagsImE+0x64)[0x1972e14]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZNK10ArmISAInst27LOAD_IMM_AY_PN_SN_UN_WN_SZ47executeEP11ExecContextPN5Trace10InstRecordE+0x12d)[0x14f95cd]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN15AtomicSimpleCPU4tickEv+0x428)[0x1e4da58]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_ZN10EventQueue10serviceOneEv+0xa1)[0x1d55f51]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_Z9doSimLoopP10EventQueue+0x38)[0x1d65fc8]
build/ARM/gem5.opt(_Z8simulatem+0xaae)[0x1d66dfe]
build/ARM/gem5.opt[0x1dbbd3d]
build/ARM/gem5.opt[0xe08e85]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x45f7)[0x7f41e3579be7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x80d)[0x7f41e357b63d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x48d8)[0x7f41e3579ec8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x80d)[0x7f41e357b63d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x48d8)[0x7f41e3579ec8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x80d)[0x7f41e357b63d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x48d8)[0x7f41e3579ec8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x80d)[0x7f41e357b63d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x7f41e357b772]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x563e)[0x7f41e357ac2e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x80d)[0x7f41e357b63d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x48d8)[0x7f41e3579ec8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x80d)[0x7f41e357b63d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x7f41e357b772]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyRun_StringFlags+0x79)[0x7f41e35755a9]
--- END LIBC BACKTRACE ---
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Minimal fully automated setup that just works: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/d29a07ddad499f273cc90dd66e40f8474b5dfc40#gem5-buildroot-setup Also I don't recommend using such old Ubuntu 14.04.